# Engine won't start without throttle-help when warm

Tags: engine, carburetor, scooter

My scooter won't start by using the kick start when warm, without help by twisting the throttle-handle a bit (at the same time as using the kick start).

By "warm" I mean it's been stored in a room with a temperature at about 20 degrees (celcius), but not been actively running in at least 7 hours.

When the temperature is 0-10 degrees (celcius) or the engine has been running for some time, it starts just fine without any help.

What causes this? Could it be a defective idle-jet or choke?

My scooter has a 50cc GY6 engine, a CV carburator and a choke.

Comment: Is there a choke?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more. What kind of scooter? How old is it? Is the gasoline fresh? When was the last time it was serviced? When it does run, does it run well?

Comment: Question edited - the scooter has a choke.

Comment: Vapor Lock? How much throttle?